# Make numeric values in different language in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, numeric, multilingual

I've been implementing a multilingual site using CodeIgniter and everything works great with translating labels or messages. However, I've got a problem in translating number in to different languages. For example, numbers range `1, 2, 3, 4,...` should be translated in to `១, ២, ៣, ៤,...` in **Khmer** language.

I think this should be `number_lang.php` file, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should handle(session,cookie,uri etc.) codeigniter's language.I think the session is better but you can also connet it with uri.You can assign a session for user's default language as a `En-English`.When user changes the language, you would change the the session as a `De-Deutsch` or another language etc.

By the way, you can use Codeigniter's language helper for using that language files (f.e: number_lang.php).
There is function to output that language variables in the following segment:

```
<?php echo lang('here_is_your_key'); ?>
```

Also, In numbers_lang.php you can wrote code that is similar with int he following segment of code for each diffrent language:

```
<?php 
$lang['here_is_your_key'] = "1";
$lang['two'] = "2";
$lang['three'] = "3";
?>
```

In controller you can use line function from language library for getting language key's value from file.It will fetch a line of text from language file with `$this->lang->line('language_key');`

Comment: I can hendle with such static assignment. But how is number generated automatically? For example, the pagination

Comment: It has got a different language path.The pagination class uses the system's language file because of that there is different language path on ci.In my opinion, you can change the system languages path dynamically, so you should write you own class.